# Sibling relationship in Big Mom family

Tags: one-piece

We see a lot of the girls trying to impress Katakuri and they get embarrassed when he looks at them and their hearts will race if they think he is going to praise them.

I don't think this is normal if they look at him only as a brother. Maybe I'm wrong to think that way (I'm an only child, not much experience with siblings) but was there ever any indication that a romantic relationship is possible between siblings in the Big Mom family?

Was there ever any indication of siblings getting married in the Big Mom family?

Comment: Don't forget that most of them have different father, so they probably just half siblings

Comment: @Darjeeling That is what makes the relationship more likely

Comment: Nah nah, it was just they admired him so much. Say if yo a guy, and like your hero (also a guy) tells you "good job". It is like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no mention about a romantic relationship or a marriage between siblings of the Big Mom Family.

We can't tell yet why his (female) siblings are behaving like that. Maybe it's because of Katakuri's past (which is unknown except for last chapter), or maybe because he's considered the strongest member of the BM Crew/Family.

---

> We see a lot of the girls trying to impress Katakuri and they get
>   embarrassed when he looks at them and their hearts will race if they
>   think he is going to praise them.

I think you're talking especially about Flambe. When she was first introduced, I thought she was representing the one-piece-community. I've read many posts about Katakuri and how cool, awesome, badass [...] he is. 
Just like Bartolomeo representing all strawhat fans.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, there are none sibling relationship between Big Mom Pirates' crew. However, we know that marriage for big mom only mean the expansion of their crew, for example, Pudding have to get married with Sanji because Big Mom want Germa66 technology, and Chiffon got married with Bege so they would join them. Considering this, even if they like each other, it's quite unlikely for her children to have some serious relationship among them unless it increase crew strength in some way.

In Wiki there's a [list of Charlotte family member](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Family#Members), and there's only two known in-laws so far: Capone Bege and Aladine. Both are not Big Mom's children